# How to override source in Linux shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

My team share a shell script, I want to make it Cygwin-compatible because only me is on Windows. Now the problem comes from `source`. My shell only accepts format like:

```
source ./<file name>
```

instead of

```
source <file name>
```

which is already in the script. So I want to override `source` like:

```
source(){ . ./$@; }
```

But now my shell complains that:

```
`source': is a special builtin
```

What should I do for now?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because of a mismatch in the $PATH?  `source` uses the $PATH if the filename isn't explicit.  Does your $PATH include `.`?  Non-explicit paths are dangerous anyway, so I would tell your developers to fix the scripts.

Comment: @EightBitTony at least with Bash on Linux, it tries `$PWD` after `$PATH`, even though there is no `.` in my `$PATH`.

Comment: Uh, no.  `$PWD` is in fact _not_ automagically fake-added to `$PATH` by default. Why would you presume this to be so?

Comment: @DopeGhoti was that directed at me? If so, I'd presume it be so because I tested it, and the bash manpage documents the behavior as well. In fact, I just tested it on a fresh Cygwin install, where it is too.

Comment: @Elderry I tried on a fresh Cygwin install, and it works for me. Is your Cygwin using a non-bash shell, or maybe your bash is set to run in POSIX mode?

Comment: Cygwin, being a Windows tool, inherits the Windows path paradigm, which _does_ roll in the current working directory.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ePDvfcF.png shows magic PWD pathing to not be the case in a non-Windows environment.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Is this also the case for `source runme`?

Comment: _"`. filename [arguments]` -- When Bash is not in POSIX mode, the current directory is searched if filename is not found in $PATH. "_ https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins But the question didn't say it was Bash

Comment: @derobert, I run the script by `sh <script name>` so I am in POSIX mode. I don't use bash because I want to keep that keyword for WSL.

Comment: @EightBitTony, you are right, now I think fix script is the correct way.

Comment: @Elderry I agree with you. The script really ought to use `source ./foo.sh` if it wants to source a file from the current working directory. If your colleagues object, point out that it's currently doing a PATH search first, and if there happened to be a `foo.sh` in PATH somewhere, it'd be run instead (probably leading to much confusion).

Answer (score 2):

From that error message about a special builtin (see http://sources.debian.net/src/bash/4.4-4/execute_cmd.c/?hl=5623#L5623), it appears you're running bash in POSIX mode. This might be because you have `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` set, ran the shell with `--posix`, used `set -o posix`, etc.

One of the many things POSIX mode does (in addition to not let you override `source`) is make `source` (and `.`) not search the current working directory if `$PATH`-lookup fails.

This has nothing to do with running on Cygwin.